# Tmux - right hand side pane moves when type in left hand side

Tags: tmux, iterm2, pane

When I have a vertical split in tmux and I type in the pane on the left, the text on the same row in the pane on the right sometimes slides to the right as I'm typing and jumps back to normal when I'm done.  I assume it's just trying to redraw as quickly as possible, but the flickering movement is distracting and I was wondering if there was any way to avoid it.

Small video clip of what's happening in case my explanation is unclear: http://www.videosprout.com/video?id=db09d78c-42cc-4f1e-80c7-a58a7c63e4f9

Comment: can you post your tmux conf and your iterm version?

Comment: iTerm 3.0.13, tmux 2.3

Comment: and your tmux conf? I'd like to reproduce it. I have used tmux in iterm in the past and never came across this issue

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GUSKj7ty

Comment: I could not reproduce, even with the same iTerm and tmux version and your tmux.conf and different window sizes. It seems that there is some other fact that that is relevant here. You might report the bug [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues). As a temporary workaround: Do you know the [iterm<->tmux](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/wikis/TmuxIntegration) integration? I've worked with it in the past and it's quite well done and should not suffer from the thing you're having here.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that integration and prefer to work with tmux on its own.

Comment: Ah sorry it was tmux 2.2.  Not sure it matters though.  Also the bug appears inconsistently.